# Pre-Loading Images

Tags: html, css, image

Is there a way to pre-load images just using html/css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. There are many tutorials available on this topic - [here is one of them](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/04/15/pure-css-better-image-preloading-without-javascript/).

Answer (score 2):

Or even easier: [`<link rel="prefetch" href="path to image">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Link_prefetching_FAQ) (Firefox).

[`<link rel="prerender" href="http://example.org/index.html">`](http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender.html) (Chrome)

Comment: Is it? I would have hoped other browsers picked it up already.

Comment: Note/update: `prefetch` is [HTML 5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-prefetch). Even though I've yet not tested which browser fully implements this feature (in 2014).

Answer (score 0):

If you include an url in your CSS, the image will be downloaded as the .css file is loaded into the document.

Comment: Not true, at least not for all browsers. Most browsers load CSS url's on demand, so hover images don't download until user hovers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:
http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/04/15/pure-css-better-image-preloading-without-javascript/

Comment: Thanks... that url was already linked to in the above (first) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. There's a technique called CSS sprites.

It basically works by loading one big image and then only displaying certain sections of the image as needed. Obviously, this technique isn't practical for every solution but it's good for many.

A List Apart has a great tutorial on this: [A List Apart: Articles: CSS Sprites: Image Slicing's Kiss of Death](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/)

Comment: We have recently embraced this and it is GREAT!

Comment: took a look at this also.  It seems very interesting.